# Google Maps geocoding API component restriction

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the [Google Maps Geocoding API web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), and I'm using the `components` parameter to restrict results to 'London'. My URL query is here:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=<address>&components=administrative_area:london, united kingdom`

This works super well and I only get results which are within London. However, if I ask for something definitely not in London, (e.g 'Manchester'), I simply get a default return relating to 'Greater London'. I would rather it simply returns the `ZERO_RESULTS` status. Is there a way to specify this?

P.S I have tried to use the `region` parameter, but this isn't as tight as I want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Using information found on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering

You can filter by a city (locality) and country as two separate filter components and these can be separated by the pipe (|) symbol. The country is the ISO 3166-1 country code [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1] therefore `GB` in order to cover the city of London.

Therefore, this format could be used :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=<address>&components=locality:London|country:UK
```

With that in mind, and addressing your exact question, according to 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering

> Filter values support the same methods of spelling correction and
>   partial matching as other geocoding requests. If a geocoding result is
>   a partial match for a component filter it will contain a partial_match
>   field in the response.

So it seems it will always try to find partial match when there are no exact matches and this cannot be disabled unfortunately.

However, if you do a check for `"partial_match" : true` in the result set, you could filter out such results in your code that deals with the response.

**In Summary**

This format seems to give results without `"partial_match" : true` if the address is ‘good’

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=<address>&components=locality:London|country:UK
```

And it will allow you to filter the response for `"partial_match" : true` in your code to exclude spurious results. For example, using an address 'Manchester' :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Manchester&components=locality:London|country:UK
```